# Using HTML in PHP Email Script

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to add some mark-up to an email that's generated by a PHP script, but it doesn't appear to be parsing the tags as they are are visible in the email along with the content. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Script:

```
<?php

$name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));
$emailFrom = $email;
$emailTo = "my@email.com";
$subject = "Subject Line";

// Prepare email body text
$body = "<strong>Name:</strong> $name <br /> Email: $email <br /> Message: $message";

$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Send email 
$success = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, "From: $name <$emailFrom>");

// Redirect to success or error pages
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=thankyou.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
}

?>
```

Output:

`<strong>Name:</strong> My Name <br /> Email: my@email.com <br /> Message: TEST`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your code, you don't use $headers

change these lines :

```
$headers  = "";  
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $name <$emailFrom>" . "\r\n";

// Send email 
$success = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

and if it's not enough to work, I advice you tu use a opensource mailer like phpmailer : http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examples

Comment: This worked! But presented another issue. Commented on other (same) answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the `$header` to you mail function.
Please add `"From: $name <$emailFrom>"` to your `$header` and then pass it to the mail function:

```
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $name <$emailFrom>" . "\r\n";

// Send email 
$success = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $header);
```

Comment: I see what you mean. That worked! The tags are now being parsed, but the from name/email is only displaying as "$name".

Comment: I'm sorry, I used the wrong type of quotes (single quotes instead of double quotes). I edited my answer. Is it working now?